How do I calculate the shape of a rotating follower such that it deflects the same amount in both directions?
I'm designing a joystick, and this problem has been beating me up for months now.
I am using a cam and rotating follower (or lever) arrangement for the return spring that looks something like this:

As you can see from the image, rotating the cam by the same amount (25deg) in either direction results in asymmetric deflection of the lever depending if the rotation is towards or away from the center point of the lever.
Here's a more rigid sketch of the system showing a lot of the relevant datums: 
I attmpted to solve this by defining an arbitrary function for the desired deflection of the lever per degree, and then solving for the needed offset at each point.
That resulted in the curve shown below, which I applied to the lever arm. 
Unfortunately, this method does not account for the size of the bearing, and the fact that the contact patch moves nonlinearly when rolling on a curved surface.
This results in almost double the intended offset when the bearing of the cam is halfway up the slope: 
So my question is, how should I go about designing that curve? Maybe I should stop thinking about it as a cam, and construct the problem simply with 2 moving bodies in a polar coordinate space? I'm totally at a loss here, and have been for quite some time despite tons of research.
For reference, here is the cam layout of a commercial joystick from an established brand: 
UPDATE 6/27/24: I believe I solved it. On the near side (rotating towards the lever center), the above solution works. However, on the far side, the solution is different. Instead of a perpendicular offset from the lever arm, you need the deflection to be applied on a line TANGENT to the bearing, through the point directly under the bearing center. Which means the offset needs to be applied in two dimensions, like so:
Now, I wouldn't really consider this a full solution, because I have no idea how or why this works. Why is it different in one direction than the other? Does it have to do with positive and negative curvature? I have no idea. If someone can help me understand why there's two solutions here I would be very grateful.

what about a T shaped follower, centered on the joystick pivot?

@jsotola I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. The only way I can imagine a T-shaped follower working is with linear motion, and I'm trying to avoid linear followers because getting smooth linear motion out of 3d printed parts is far more difficult than rotational, since the tolerances need to be much tighter.

So, is the problem statement as follows "the roller diameter 8, on a lever length L, moves by 25 degrees from vertical in both directions away from the vertical, to result in a linear angular displacement of the shaped arm,  with a distance X between the pivot of the arm and the initial position of the roller" ? If so the geometry is not very hard to work out, but before I'd attempt it I'd want the unknown dimensions identified. Any cam designing software would probably work, not that I have access to that.

@GregLocock The unknown dimensions are not critical, but for my calculations I was using: 20mm center of roller to roller pivot, 20mm from bottom of bearing to lever center. Here's the spreadsheet that got me to where I am now.
If this geometry seems easy to you, you must be some sort of gigagenius lol

@GregLocock also, the displacement of the lever does not need to be linear. I would phrase the problem more like "given some function relating roller angle and lever angle, find the offset needed such that the angular position of both parts follow the function"
The most elegant solution would allow me to plug in some function (say, displacement = 0.02(roller angle)^2)and produce the curve needed to relate the two

I would imagine the mechanism  in the desired position at many points and then bite chunks out of the follower where the roller overlaps at each of those points. If you do this and then interpolate in between that should get you fairly close. Otherwise you're just looking at a difficult math function.

Yeah, this^ This looks like a problem that's easy enough to solve iteratively?

@JonathanRSwift The problem with an iterative solution like that is that I don't have (or know of) a software that would make that process easy enough to do repeatedly. An analytical solution would allow me to try out different functions rapidly without the tedious process of "biting out" the curve every time. Thankfully I seem to have found a method that works (see edit), but it's not quite a full solution yet.

You have to use an iterative approach because the contact angle between the roller and the lever affects the location of the contact point for a given angle a, so it shuffles around as you modify the profile.  I think you've oversimplified the geometry in your original spreadsheet, is the modified one working?

This is not a complete answer but I think it establishes the geometry and an approach for a solution.

So E is the pivot for the follower, C is the pivot for the cam/roller.ED is the reference axis for the follower. A is the centre of the 8mm roller, B is the contact point to the line segment defined by the length if the two perpendiculars to the follower's axis at F and G, to I and H.
So, start at one end of the profile, move the cam/roller to one extreme. Move F and G so their perpendiculars are to either side of B and adjust the lengths of the perpendiculars to reach the correct value of the angle of the follower , for the angle of the cam/roller.
Now move the cam/roller to its next position, and move either F or G, and adjust the length of the new perpendicular to get the correct value for the angle of the follower.
The trick here is that we aren't defining the height of the profile at a given value of the roller/cam's position, but define a sequence of tangential lines to form the profile.
